# Boot from CD Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning

I have Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS running installed on vmware (without LVM), i want to extend the root partition disk space,so i am trying to boot first from CD, i tried both ways:
- tried to boot from iso, which i used to install the server.
- tried to boot from real DVD from the DVD PC drive,

But in both trials, i couldn't find the "Try ubuntu" option, it always shows me installation list

[image]

Comment: Does server have a `try` option ? Theres nothing really to try, make it with desktop version http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop

Comment: I am not sure, i just want to boot from cd so that i can resize the root partition, thats why i am looking for something like "try" on the ubuntu server cd/iso.

Comment: Can you not make a desktop USB or DVD ? I just read athread that said no `try ubuntu` on server or alternative install ISO though I cannot confirm this 100% it is likely true

Comment: I didn't get your comment clearly, do you mean i can boot ubuntu server by "Desktop version"?

Comment: The Ubuntu server installation image has no try-out option. You need to use a desktop image. I fired it up in a VM, there is no try-out option.

Comment: No download the desktop ISO from Ubuntu.com and make a CD of that to boot with, thanks for confirmation @Nephente

Comment: I didn't think that i can use ubuntu desktop version cd to boot on a server version, i will try that and let you know, many thanks :)

Comment: No you can't boot a server version from it but you can open a tty (ctrl+alt+F1) and enter all commands there just the same

Comment: **user225844** You should boot the desktop version from CD, choose the try option, do the resize with that desktop version and then reboot normally in the server version...  Can you confirm you understood? **@Nephente**: as you were the first to notice: can you convert that to an answer and rop me a note afterwards here so I can come back and upvote?  **;-)**

Comment: @user225844 Don't thank people: wait for an answer to be published and then "accept" it by clicking the ☑ to the left of the answer: much better then thanking people as that will [validate the answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Well, if you insist ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ubuntu Server image does not offer a "Try Ubuntu" option like the desktop image does. Booting the image in a VM confirmed OP's experience.

I suppose one reason is, that the server image does not pack any desktop environments - if you select any such package during installation it will be downloaded from the internet. Quote [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_desktop_and_server.3F):

> The "Server" CD avoids including what Ubuntu considers desktop packages (packages like X, Gnome or KDE)[...]

If you need a rescue system with a GUI, boot the desktop image. No problem at all.

Comment: I know I can be a pain in the lower abdomen, but now we've got a nice new shiny question *with an answer that is going to help a ton of other people!*  **;-)**